# How to compare daily price to the latest 5 days?

Tags: python, list, indexing

I want to find out if daily price is greater than the last of 5 recent days.
I am new to programming. But even i know this is way to much code.

```
DAILY_PRICE = [ 1,2,3,6,5,6,7,8,5,6,7,6,7,5] 
COMMENT =  IN REALITY DAILY_PRICE LIST IS FULL OF STOCK PRICES

PRICE = DAILY_PRICE[-1]
PRICE1 = DAILY_PRICE[-2]
PRICE2 = DAILY_PRICE[-3]
PRICE3 = DAILY_PRICE[-4]
PRICE4 = DAILY_PRICE[-5]
PRICE5 = DAILY_PRICE[-6]

if PRICE > PRICE1:
    print("YES")
else:
    print("NO")

if PRICE > PRICE1 and PRICE > PRICE2:
    print("YES")
else:
    print("NO")
if PRICE > PRICE1 and PRICE > PRICE2 and PRICE > PRICE3:
    print("YES")
else:
    print("NO")
if PRICE > PRICE1 and PRICE > PRICE2 and PRICE > PRICE3 and  PRICE >  PRICE4:
    print("YES")
else:
    print("NO")


if PRICE > PRICE1 and PRICE > PRICE2 and PRICE > PRICE3 and PRICE >   PRICE4 and PRICE > PRICE5:
    print("YES")
else:
    print("NO")

COMMENT = THE PRINTS IS ONLY THERE FOR CONFIRMATION, LATER I WILL STORE THE TRUE OR FALSE VALUES IN OTHER VARIABLES
```

Comment: Why do you provide `[ 1,2,3,6,5,6,7,8,5,6,7,6,7,5]` as data if only the last 5 days matter? Wouldn't `[ 5,6,7,6,7,5]` be enough?

Comment: Loop back from the upper bound of your array 5 elements one at a time as long as the index variable (the loop controller) is not less than 0.

Comment: If you are writing this in python, I think you are looking for the for loop operator.  Which will allow you to iterate over the items in a list and perform some action on them.  

You can move backwards in a list using the reversed() and you can specify that only 5 items should be itterated using the range().

Answer (score 1):

Use [all](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all):

```
DAILY_PRICE = [ 1,2,3,6,5,6,7,8,5,6,7,6,7,5] 

greater_than_last_5 = all(DAILY_PRICE[-1] > price for price in DAILY_PRICE[-6:-1])

print(greater_than_last_5)
# False
```

Comment: Thank you, but if I want to compare it to each of the last 5 days?

Answer (score 0):

Use list slicing with [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) and [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) checking on the slice of your data that includes the 5 indexes befoure your current index:

This code will provide output for a sliding 5 day window over your whole data list:

```
DAILY_PRICE =  [ 1,2,3,6,5,6,7,8,5,6,7,6,7,5]  
#                          ^ window starts here, before it is less then 5 days of data


for index,price in enumerate(DAILY_PRICE):
    if index < 5 :
        continue # no comparison for first 5 prices

    if all(p <= price for p in DAILY_PRICE[index-5:index]):
        print(f"All prices {DAILY_PRICE[index-5:index]} lower/equal then {price}")
    else:
        print(f"Not all prices {DAILY_PRICE[index-5:index]} lower/equal then {price}")
```

Output:

```
All prices [1, 2, 3, 6, 5] lower/equal then 6
All prices [2, 3, 6, 5, 6] lower/equal then 7
All prices [3, 6, 5, 6, 7] lower/equal then 8
Not all prices [6, 5, 6, 7, 8] lower/equal then 5
Not all prices [5, 6, 7, 8, 5] lower/equal then 6
Not all prices [6, 7, 8, 5, 6] lower/equal then 7
Not all prices [7, 8, 5, 6, 7] lower/equal then 6
Not all prices [8, 5, 6, 7, 6] lower/equal then 7
Not all prices [5, 6, 7, 6, 7] lower/equal then 5   # this is the one your code tries to do
                                                    # all(p <= DAILY_PRICE[-1] for p 
                                                    #                in DAILY_PRICE[-6:-1])
```

Comment: This seems to do a lot that wasn't in the original question, whichobscures the parts that *do* directly relate to it.

Comment: @Scott he gave more then 6 datapoints - this makes only sense if he wants a sliding window, not only for the last 5 datapoints. Thierry provided the last 5 days of the list, I provided the sliding window.

Comment: Right; I don't see anything in the question about needing a sliding window.

Comment: @Scott:   `COMMENT =  IN REALITY DAILY_PRICE LIST IS FULL OF STOCK PRICES` ... what do you guess - to make sure I asked in a comment as well. Doubt it gets a fast reponse though.

Comment: "if daily price is greater than the last of 5 recent days." sounds like OP only needs last 5 days, regardless of how many are in the list, not EVERY 5-day window.